# How to do Multiple file transfer to any dropbox account using Dropbox API?

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, google-drive-api, dropbox, google-api-nodejs-client

We are currently working on a project in which we are storing the data (images and videos stored in Amazon S3) of our users(photographers). Now we are keeping their data with us only for a certain period of months after that the data will be deleted from Amazon S3. The users are requesting if we can move their data to Dropbox/Google Drive for some sort of backup. But there can be approx 8000 photos and videos that should be backed up, is there any way we can do this multiple file transfer using the Dropbox APIs?

Comment: Dropbox does offer [an API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) that includes [the ability to upload files to Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload), as well as [an official JavaScript SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/javascript), which includes [the same functionality](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesUpload__anchor).

Comment: But can we submit multiple upload requests at once in this?

Comment: You can't upload multiple files per request, so you need to call once per file.

Comment: Is the issue performance? You could use multithreading or asynchronous API calls to Dropbox to download files quicker

Comment: @alexwennerberg can we use auth token received from the dropbox and do this in the backend? The transfer might be between from 10-20 GB.

Comment: Just to put some numbers out there... in my experience it takes about a quarter of a second to upload a single (small) file via the dropbox API. If you have thousands of files, that's a problem.